# how to enable url rewriting in nginx on windows pc

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I am using winginx on windows 8.1 pro. I am new to using it. I want to enable url rewriting for nginx on windows so that link like this"http://mysite.dev/portfolio/latest/business-card-design/" works fine. I want to work with wordpress and laravel specially. I found how to convert .htaccess file to nginx but I do not know where to put them. I hope you expert people understand my problem. sorry for my English. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look here : [nginx http rewrite module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html), it can help you to do what you are looking for.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your reply. but I am sorry that I could not solve my problem using the link. I am really new to nginx. I do not know how to configure url rewriting for wordpress pretty url. It is a fast server than xmapp. but I am very sad that I can not make it work for my wordpress theme development with pretty url. I search on google on youtube for solution but could not find proper solution. Please help me with easy to understand details. Thank you very much.

Comment: Don't be hasty, take your time to find what you are looking for and to do what you want. I don't know exactly how to do with nginx for wordpress but I know that google know it ;) so take a look [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/WordPress) and [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx).

Comment: Hello, I am not hasty, I spent more than 7 days on researching a solution to enable pretty url for wordpress on nginx on windows but I can not achieve the result. as All the information you gave me is over complicated for a newbie like me. They did not say clearly which file to edit and where to put some code to enable pretty url. Isn't there any way to enable url rewrite like a simple process .htaccess file? kindly consider that I am not expert. I am totally new to nginx. I really need some easy solution. Please kindly help me with a straight forward solution. THanks

Comment: OK, I put an answer, take a look and tell me if it's OK for you.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded [Winginx](http://winginx.com/en/download) and installed [Wordpress 4.0.1](https://wordpress.org/download/) and this is my configuration :

```
server {

    listen 127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    root home/example.com/public_html;

    index index.php index.html;

    log_not_found off;
    access_log logs/example.com-access.log;

    charset utf-8;

    location ~ /\. { deny all; }
    location = /favicon.ico { }
    location = /robots.txt { }      

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

With this configuration, generated by Winginx, my site works fine and the only part that I have added is the URL rewrite part :

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
}
```

Of course you have to select your permalinks settings from Settings > Permalinks to get what you want as URLs.

Comment: Thank you soooooooooooooooooooooooo much my dear. It works. I had to change server name, root's value according to my server name and its root. Wooow. it works great. I am extremely happy. Thank you again for your great help.